# Django blank select field

Tags: django, django-forms

I a have a django form which is a select field called `piece` which will be populated as a ModelChoiceField:

```
class ProjectInfoForm(forms.Form):
    module = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Module.objects.all(),
    )
    piece = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Piece.objects.all(),
    )
```

I initially had this as above where the field loaded up all the `piece` objects initially. However, this is uneccessary as the `piece` field is populated via ajax depending on what the user selects for `module`.

My question is, what is the best way to initalize this `piece` field as a blank select field, with maybe one empty label, along the lines of '--------'?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `-------` option just make it an optional field with `required=False` and to start with no choices use an empty queryset with `Piece.objects.none()`:

```
class ProjectInfoForm(forms.Form):
    module = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Module.objects.all(),
    )
    piece = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=Piece.objects.none(),
        required=False,
    )
```

Comment: Great. Love the simplicity!